# Generate rows based on value in 2 columns. Bug?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, optimization, query-performance

I have the following table in Oracle:

```
  ID     START  END
_ID01   AB050   AB100
_ID01   AB101   AB150
_ID02   AB0251  AB0300
_ID01   AB00301 AB00302
```

I want to generate as many rows and every records defines. So the first need 50 more with a new col start with AB50 up to AB100. **Everything works fine**, *but if I don't add that junk row, the sql developer can't solve the problem, just* **loading**.

I tried with some random SQL hint but none of them worked. Need some advice or hint what's "wrong" with my working query, because I don't think that's normal behavior.

And my SQL query is the following.

```
     with m as (
      select  to_number(substr(t.START,3)) as num
      from FCS_FP_TOMB t
      where t.START ='AB0251' --<--- THIS ROW IS A JUNK BUT DOESNT WORK WITHOUT IT
     ),
      n as (
      select level - 1 as n
      from m
      connect by level <= m.num + 1
     )
select  ft0.*, regexp_substr(ft0.START,'([A-Z])+')||to_char(to_number(substr(ft0.START,3)) + n.n) as "bizonylat"
from FCS_FP_TOMB ft0 join
     n
     on to_number(substr(ft0.START,3)) + n.n <= to_number(substr(ft0.END,3))

 order by 2,3,7
     ;
```

The out put:

```
...
_ID01   AB050   AB100   AB098
_ID01   AB050   AB100   AB099
_ID01   AB050   AB100   AB100
_ID01   AB101   AB150   AB101
_ID01   AB101   AB150   AB102
...
```

**EDIT**: I tried `MATERIALIZE` and `INLINE` hints, and my Oracle server is 10g.

Comment: There were several issues with CTEs in Oracle. You should mention exact version you use. I'd recommend you to use hins MATERIALIZE and INLINE on factored sub-queries to see if query output changes. I also saw situation where dropping functional index on the table, changed the result of the query.

Comment: I tried both of these hints none of them worked :/

Comment: What happens if you replace the CTE with: `with n as (select level-1 as n
      from dual
      connect by level <= 100) select ft0.* ...` (the rest remains unchanged, no `m` at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your query. The CTE `m` will return not a single row, but as many rows as in `FCS_FP_TOMB`. Then you are putting *all* of those rows into the row generator CTE `n`, whereas a row generator construct like you're using should get a single row.

What I would do is to define `m` to return a single row with the minimum and maximum values, and then subtract these in `n` to get the number of rows you need to generate.

Something like (untested):

```
with m as (
  select max(to_number(substr(t.END,3))) - min(to_number(substr(t.START,3))) as num
  from FCS_FP_TOMB t
), n as (
  select level - 1 as n
  from m
  connect by level <= m.num + 1
)
select ft0.*, regexp_substr(ft0.START,'([A-])+')||to_char(to_number(substr(ft0.START,3)) + n.n) as "bizonylat"
from FCS_FP_TOMB ft0
join n on to_number(substr(ft0.START,3)) + n.n <= to_number(substr(ft0.END,3))
order by 2,3,7;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `max(to_number(substr(t.END,3))) - min(...t.START...)` ?

Comment: Or `max( to_number(substr(t.END,3)) - to_number(substr(t.START,3)) )`

Comment: Something like that... my brain hurts! If you have 1-2 and 99-100, you'd only need 2 generated rows -- but you'd have to add the row numbers to the start value when generating the labels.

Comment: thanks Colin, its actually fix my problem. Can anyone explain it why i need that max-min? :O. I Try to understand but I simply can't